# C# Fade-in and fade-out transparency when form is being moved

Tags: c#, transparency, fadein, fadeout

I have the code to make the form partially transparent when is being moved, but I want to know if it's possible to add fade-in and fade-out effects when I start moving and stop moving the form.

**EDIT**

The code I am using to add transparency to the form is:

```
        bool canMove = false;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        canMove = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            this.Opacity = 0.7;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Add fade-in and fade-out effects.
That's what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `Timer` control, set the opacity in timer's tick event. until the form stops moving (define a variable like `isMoving` and set it to true/false based on form's status).

You can find an example of setting opacity in timer's tick event in [my article](http://www.devzone.ir/post/1389/09/20/Winforms-FadingLabel.aspx) about a fading label. Use Google translator to read it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Timer` control, you could then start the timer when form starts moving and set the `transparency` of the form to some value, and on each `tick` of the `Timer`, make the `transparency` to `decrease` and on some value make it to `increase`. If you want to have the fadein fadeout effect when form stops moving, you can do the same when the form has moved.